# Using a function in a while loop (works in Atom but not in VIM)

Tags: c

I've been tasked with creating a shift cipher where I take a string from a user and either, encrypt, decrypt, move the shift variable, or quit. The code I've written works perfectly in Atom but when I try it in VIM (from where I have to submit it from) everything works except: The output is blank whenever my encrypt or decrypt function runs.

```
    int main(){
    int shift = 3;
    char stringresponse[SIZE];

    while (1 || 2 || 3){
     switch(getUserChoice()){
case 1:
   shift = getShift();
    break;
case 2:
    getString(stringresponse);
    encrypt(stringresponse,shift);
    break;
case 3:
    getString(stringresponse);
    decrypt(stringresponse,shift);
    break;
default :
    printf("Exiting the program");
    exit(0);
   }
   }
   return 0;
   }

   int getUserChoice(){
     int userchoice = 0;
     char dump = 0;
      printf("--------------------------------\n");
      printf("| 1) Change Shift (Default 3) |\n");
      printf("| 2) Encrypt a message |\n");
      printf("| 3) Decrypt a message) |\n");
      printf("| 4) Quit) |\n");
      printf("--------------------------------\n");

      printf("Option: ");
      scanf(" %d%c",&userchoice,&dump);

      return userchoice;
     }

    int getShift(){
     int newshift = 0;
     char dump = 0;
     printf("Enter a new shift value:");
     scanf("%d,%c",&newshift,&dump);

    return newshift;
    }

void getString(char buf[]){
 printf(" Input: ");
 fgets(buf,SIZE,stdin);

   }

  void encrypt(char buf[], int shift){
   int i = 0;

     while(buf[i] != '\0'){
       if (buf[i] == 32){
             buf[i] = buf[i];
             i++;
        }
      else if (buf[i] == 10){
        buf[i] == 32;
        i++;
        }
    else{
    buf[i] -= shift;
    i++;
    }

  }
  printf("Output: %5s\n",buf);
   }

  void decrypt(char buf[], int shift){
    int i = 0;

     while(buf[i] != '\0'){
       if (buf[i] == 32){
            buf[i] = buf[i];
            i++;
        }
       else if (buf[i] == 10){
        buf[i] == 32;
        i++;
      }
       else{
       buf[i] += shift;
       i++;
       }

  }
    printf("Output: %5s\n",buf);
  }
```

Comment: How are you compiling/executing it in each scenario?

Comment: The text editor you use to write code has absolutely no bearing on how it functions. To run C code you need to run it through a compiler. I'm not aware of any way to do this automatically through vim, have you tried compiling from the command line?

Comment: Where is SIZE coming from?

Comment: What is `while (1 || 2 || 3)` supposed to mean?

Comment: so SIZE is being declared as 500, don't have that in the code included. I ran the code through Atom and Codeblocks (compiled it there as well) and in both situations it ran correctly, however when I ran in Vim that's when I get blank output for my encrpyt/decrypt functions. while while (1 || 2 || 3) is supposed to be while the case is 1 2 or 3 then run the getUserChoice function, would that be a logical error? in VIM I run gcc <filename> to compile and then ./.a.out to run it, I don't get a compiler error but the output is as stated before.

Comment: If you run the corrected  code from my answer through VIM and gcc, what happens?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau same issue. It gives me a blank output when the encrypt and decrypt function works. I've run the code in both Codeblocks and Atom and it works, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Time to do some line by line debugging I guess.

Comment: Are you sure a.out is recent? What is the timestamp on that? Also try creating your own executable name like gcc filename outfilename

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: So I submitted the assignment and it ran correctly for my professor, I also realized later that I was trying to use the results from my getUserChoice function in the while loop incorrectly, however this wasn't the cause of the error. Still not sure what cause it, but it ran correctly on my other editors/compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code above and these are the types of errors I encountered (VC++ command line)

> error C2371: 'getString': redefinition; different basic types

Moved the functions above `main()` as functions should be declared before being used.

> error C2065: 'SIZE': undeclared identifier

I replaced `SIZE` with `1024` for testing for this.

Also warnings:

> warning C4553: '==': result of expression not used; did you intend '='?

For these

```
else if (buf[i] == 10){
buf[i] == 32;
i++;
}
```

Complete and formatted and changed code I used for testing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getUserChoice()
{
    int userchoice = 0;
    char dump = 0;
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    printf("| 1) Change Shift (Default 3) |\n");
    printf("| 2) Encrypt a message |\n");
    printf("| 3) Decrypt a message |\n");
    printf("| 4) Quit) |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------\n");

    printf("Option: ");
    scanf(" %d%c", &userchoice, &dump);

    return userchoice;
}

int getShift()
{
    int newshift = 0;
    char dump = 0;
    printf("Enter a new shift value:");
    scanf("%d,%c", &newshift, &dump);

    return newshift;
}

void getString(char buf[])
{
    printf(" Input: ");
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
}

void encrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (buf[i] == 32)
        {
            buf[i] = buf[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (buf[i] == 10)
        {
            buf[i] = 32;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            buf[i] -= shift;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("Output: %5s\n", buf);
}

void decrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (buf[i] == 32)
        {
            buf[i] = buf[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (buf[i] == 10)
        {
            buf[i] = 32;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            buf[i] += shift;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("Output: %5s\n", buf);
}

int main()
{
    int shift = 3;
    char stringresponse[1024];

    while (1 || 2 || 3)
    {
        switch (getUserChoice())
        {
            case 1:
                shift = getShift();
                break;
            case 2:
                getString(stringresponse);
                encrypt(stringresponse, shift);
                break;
            case 3:
                getString(stringresponse);
                decrypt(stringresponse, shift);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Exiting the program");
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the  `while ( 1 || 2 || 3)` loop is a funny way of writing `while (1)`.